# Compare lines in two files

Tags: bash

I have a CSV formatted file as shown below:

[image]

I applied an Excel formula to count the number of occurrences of each user to know the total number of privileges which each user has in the year 2019:

[image]

I have now obtained a similar file from the previous year (2018) to identify the following:

- New privileges obtained by the users in this year
- Identify if there are any new users which are listed in year 2019 but not listed in year 2018

I would appreciate your help to do the above by using a bash shell script.

Comment: I would do it in Excel instead of Bash.

Comment: `csvsql` (from the `csvkit`) package might be a good choice - I'm not going to attempt an answer based on *pictures* of the data though: if you want help, please post the actual data as text

Answer (score 0):

This is easily done using awk. Let's assume that your csv file is called table2018.txt (field separator is comma).
Let's us further assume that your USERs are in column 1.
Try this:

```
awk -F"," '{a[$1]++} END {for (i in a) print i, a[i]}' table2018.txt
```

No headers allowed in this case. So the first line must be a data line.
If the first line is header then use start the count from the second line by:

```
awk -F"," 'NR>1 {a[$1]++} END {for (i in a) print i, a[i]}' table2018.txt
```